# Interrupt command line process with nodejs after exec()

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Say I'm using something like this with node:

```
exec('ls -a',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
      console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      }
  });
```

...and imagine the command I put in there takes a bit longer to complete than a simple `ls` on a personal computer.

**Question:** How could I now programmatically stop/interrupt the execution of this command line process?

**My Attempt:** I have tried to just exit node with `process.exit(1);`, but the command line process is still running afterwards.

Comment: Have you tried using `killall`? What is the actual command used?

Comment: the actual command plays an audio file via the command line like so: `play /home/pi/scripts/alarm/first/motivational_riseandshine.mp3`

Comment: Have you tried `killall play`?

Comment: I have not, but I am now :)

Comment: It does work like this. Is this the best / correct way to do it? It throws an error afterwards, so I was wondering whether this is correct. But yeah, it works, amazing! :)

Comment: What is the error thrown?